# what's wrong with this automatic creation of charts for time spent on webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, jqplot

**!SOLVED!**

I want to **automatically create charts** with users and their **time spent on pages** of a website.

I have a file - "log.xml" where I keep information with users (customers), visited pages, dates and their time spent; and after I "get" this Xml file with Ajax, I want to parse it and create with values "extracted" charts with JqPlot.

**My problem** is that I can't loop through more than just one customer and it don't build chart for the single customer.

If I **remove the code block** with initialization of variable `plot` I **can loop** through all my customers from Xml.

Please, if someone can tell me what is wrong, and how to create charts for all customers...

Here is the code of the file "**log.xml**":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
  <customer id="14" name="Florin Virdol">
    <page name="/mobilestore/index.php">
      <date_ts on="2011-12-02" timeSpent="205"/>
    </page>
    <page name="/mobilestore/products_all.php">
      <date_ts on="2011-12-02" timeSpent="15"/>
    </page>
  </customer>
  <customer id="0" name="guest">
   <page name="/mobilestore/services.php">
      <date_ts on="2011-12-02" timeSpent="50"/>
    </page>
  </customer>
</log>
```

Here is the javascript code of the "operations":

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //read from xml
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "log.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});//ready          

//parse xml          
function parseXml(xml) {
    var i = 0;
    $(xml).find("customer").each(function() {
        $('<div class = "jqplot graph" id = "chart' + i + '"></div>').appendTo('#content');
        var customerName = $(this).attr("name");                                     
        var line_inside = [];  // declare as array               
        $(this).find("page").each(function() {
          var pageName = $(this).attr("name"); 
          $(this).find("date_ts").each(function() {
            var timeSpent_ = $(this).attr("timeSpent");//if mai multe timespent, sa faca totalul, else singuru; timespent
            line_inside.push([pageName,timeSpent_]); //do not string cat, push onto array
          });                        
        });                    
        var line = '[' + line_inside + ']';
        //--------jqplot----!!! if i remove this block, will loop through customers------------
        var plot = $.jqplot('chart' + i, [line_inside], 
        {                            
            title: customerName,
            series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    label: 'Web Page',
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions: { labelPosition:'middle',  angle: -30 }  
                },
                yaxis: {
                    autoscale:true,
                    label: 'Total Time Spent',
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions: { labelPosition:'middle', angle: -30 }
                }
            }
        });
        //-------jqplot----!!! if i remove this block, will loop through customers------------                                
        i++;
    });//find customer            
}//parse xml
```

**SOLUTION**: made modifications that **Mark** suggested, and it works.
(now, above code works!)

Comment: If the looping stops when you execute that block of code, I suspect you're probably getting a runtime error.  Do any errors appear in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: there's no errors in the JavaScript console of my browser.

Comment: Your XML is missing a close tag `</customer>` for the first customer record.  Is that just a typo?

Comment: Sorry for that, it was just a typo; I was generating the Xml from my Mysql DataBase and is valid. Here i just extracted two customers from the hole Xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing strings that look like arrays and not actual arrays to jqplot.

[Try](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/cK7qN/1/):

```
var line_inside = [];  // declare as array               
$(this).find("page").each(function() {
  var pageName = $(this).attr("name"); 
  $(this).find("date_ts").each(function() {
    var timeSpent_ = $(this).attr("timeSpent");//if mai multe timespent, sa faca totalul, else singuru; timespent
    line_inside.push([pageName,timeSpent_]); //do not string cat, push onto array
  });                        
});
alert(line_inside); // this is an array of arrays                                   
var plot = $.jqplot('chart' + i, [line_inside],
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a different plot for each customer, you need to make plot a local var to your inline function: "var plot" not just "plot" -- same goes for "line". You are assigning a global scope variable and overwriting it each time, currently.

Comment: i made this modifications as you said, but it has no effect...   
  
    var line = '[' + line_inside + ']';   
 
    var plot = $.jqplot('chart' + i, [line],